# How can I fix a php function bool?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I dont know what is the problem with this function:

```
function server_grafico_expirar($data) {
    $data = sanitize($data);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `data_exp` FROM `settings` WHERE `data_exp` = '$data'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

This function was supposed to return true if the date('d.m.Y') equals the date in mysql.

Im using like this:

```
$data = date('d.m.Y');
if(server_grafico_expirar($data)){
    echo "Today, is the date!";
}
```

The error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/mcser325/public_html/checker.php on line 35
```

Comment: Instead of what you wanted it to do. What did it actually do?

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: It was supposed to return true if the date('d.m.Y') equals the date in mysql.It just check the date..

Comment: In order to identify the problem: (1) `echo $data;` (2) Fetch the `data_exp` from the database and echo it as well.

Comment: You can echo $query and run it on phpmyadmin, I suppose it will tell you what the problem is

Comment: Sorry... I forgot tu write the error.

Comment: Well thats a syntax error....just find it, and fix it

Comment: This syntax error is in the IF
     if(server_grafico_expirar($data)){

Comment: what version of php r u using.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but it should be noted that the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must make sure that the `settings` table does contain a row that has the data_exp column set to todays date in the format d.m.Y.

mysql_result retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set. The cell that you are retrieving is data_exp. From your question I have assumed that data_exp is a date in the format of d.m.Y.

With that said, mysql_result($query, 0) will **never** be equal to 1 as it will return the date you are selecting. You could approach this in two ways, you could either check if the cell equals $data and then return true

```
function server_grafico_expirar($data) {
   $data = sanitize($data);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `data_exp` FROM `settings` WHERE `data_exp` = '$data'");
   return mysql_result($query, 0) == $data;
}
```

You could also check how many rows are returned. If more than zero rows are returned then you can return true.

```
function server_grafico_expirar($data) {
   $data = sanitize($data);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `data_exp` FROM `settings` WHERE `data_exp` = '$data'");
   return mysql_num_rows($query) > 0;
}
```

Please note that the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: Working fine now... Thanksss

Comment: You don't need a ternary operation here. `return mysql_num_rows($query) > 0` is enough.

Comment: Good point @Shikiryu, i've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from any other potential errors, what your [PHP](http://php.net/) parser is saying is that there is a *syntax* error. It's not in what you showed us at least, but make sure that you've closed every corresponding curly brackets (`{ }`) and they are properly matched up and that all lines end with a semicolon (`;`).

I'd suggest indenting properly to find the error more easily.